# Unable to enter and plot negative data in SciDaVis and QtiPlot

Tags: scidavis

I have been using SciDaVis for plotting and a variety of numeric tasks. However, now, when I try to enter negative data into a SciDaVis table, the data is just ignored. I am using my system default decimal format (that is 1 000,0 with , as the data separator comma (. in US format).

I know that the development of SciDaVis is pretty much dead right now. However, the same problem occured in the (actively developed?) QtiPlot.

Has anyone got any ideas about what might fix my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the default numeric format is switched to using . as comma, negative data is accepted! It seems muParser is unable to use negative data with , as data separator (?).

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find the solution. If this hasn't been reported as a bug, [it should be](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).